# Advantages of Defining a Contructor Using Colon C++

Tags: c++, constructor

My professor was going over constructors for classes and created them this way ...

```
ArrayList::ArrayList() : items{new std::string[10]), sz{0} {
}
```

What is the particular advantage in writing the constructor in this manner as opposed to

```
items = new std::string[10];
sz = 0;
```

Comment: That's not "declaring", that's "defining".

Comment: Ah, thank you. Still, the question stands. Do you happen to know the answer to this?

Comment: Nvm, the duplicate redirect helped me.